# PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback Error without any function name

Tags: plugins, php

I am getting the following php error:

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '' not found or invalid function name in /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
```

The issue is that there is no function name mentioned, how can I identify which function is causing this error?

Comment: That error suggests that there's a call made to `add_action()` or `add_filter()` where the callback is an "empty" one - e.g. it's `''` as in `add_action( 'init', '' )` or maybe `add_action( 'hook_name', $func )` where `$func` is empty (`NULL`, `''`, etc.). [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) can help you identify the *hook name* and also the plugin/theme file, if it's caused by a code in a plugin or the active theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a filter in the child theme causing the issue:

```
add_action('excerpt_length','')
```